# Set the state of an item in a RecyclerView selected when click on it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, selecteditem

I think this will be very easy to implement but after hours of searching I could not find something useful to get it working.
I want to set selected the item that the user clicks in a Drawer, this list is an RecyclerView. In the ViewHolder of my adapter I have an onClick event for the items:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);
   selectedItem = getPosition();
   notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);
}
```

selectedItem is an int to track the selected item.

Now in the onBindViewHolder I do this:

```
holder.itemView.setSelected(position == selectedItem);
```

But it seems that the selected state is never called because I have a android:background seted to the items row with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/border_bottom_selected"
        android:color="@color/backgroundToolbar"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/border_bottom" />
</selector>
```

The normal state is working so I know that the background is well applied.

So, how can I set the selected state to an item in a RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after digging a little more and trying to understand the way that has android to implement the styles from an xml, I found that to change the text color (something I did not tell in my question) in the specific TextView you have to set the property `android:color="@drawable/bg_item"` (bg_item is the file that contains the selector and in each item the property android:color), something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/border_bottom_selected"
        android:color="@color/backgroundToolbar" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/border_bottom"
        android:color="@color/colorTextTitleTab"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Remove the onclick listener from view holder.

In onBindViewHolder do this:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);
            selectedItem = position;
            notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);
        }
    });
    holder.itemView.setSelected(position == selectedItem);
```

I hope this might solve your problem.

Comment: Nothing, the item selected state is not showing either.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use a RecyclerView with **items that contain a TextView**.

This will allow the `TextView` to get the focus state:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```